# Getting most viewed simple products

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, filter, products

I'm getting most viewed products with this code: But I want to filter simple products

```
$productCount = 3;
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); 
$_mostViewed = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->addViewsCount()
        ->setPageSize($productCount);
```

I researched and found this code `->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))` They said it can filter by simple products. But it doesnt work. Is anyone know why?

Comment: var_dump() one collection object and check whether does it contains any attribute as 'type_id'

Comment: is it showing any error?

Comment: @DRAJI no, not given any error, but didnt filter :/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `addViewCount` method which resets the select object (see `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addViewCount()`), effectively removing your filters. Call `addViewsCount` first:

```
$_mostViewed = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                ->addViewsCount() // <-- apply collection filters *after* this call
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                ->setPageSize($productCount);
```

But being dependent on which method is called first is not exactly error prone, so make sure you wrap this behavior in some specialized method and document it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')
```

Comment: I tried it, but nothing happened.